# Send notifications in Dynamics CRM

Tags: node.js, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I'm trying to send a notifications to a client (node.js) when a certain task occurs. For exemple, if an incident is created, it should send a notification to the client.

Is there a solution to do that in Dynamics CRM out of the box or do I have to write a specific plugin ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: It depends on how you want the user to be notified: a popup in his browser, an e-mail sent to him, a task added to his queue... What are your requirements?

Comment: The notification has to be a http post request to a web client with the related object in JSON

Comment: In CRM 2011 this is not possible. An alternative could be to apply a polling mechanism in your web client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [WebRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/debx8sh9(v=VS.110).aspx) can be used to easily HTTP POST something.

You can build a plugin assembly which would act as "dispatcher", and then register it where you need it. Note that you *might* have to put the assembly outside of the sandbox (Isolation mode: none).

You also can easily set it up for each registered step through the (un)secure configuration.

The linked MSDN page for [WebRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/debx8sh9(v=VS.110).aspx) provides the following example:

```
public class WebRequestPostExample
{
    public static void Main ()
    {
        // Create a request using a URL that can receive a post. 
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create ("http://www.contoso.com/PostAccepter.aspx ");
        // Set the Method property of the request to POST.
        request.Method = "POST";
        // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
        string postData = "This is a test that posts this string to a Web server.";
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (postData);
        // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        // Get the request stream.
        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream ();
        // Write the data to the request stream.
        dataStream.Write (byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        // Close the Stream object.
        dataStream.Close ();
        // Get the response.
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse ();
        // Display the status.
        Console.WriteLine (((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
        // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream ();
        // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (dataStream);
        // Read the content.
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd ();
        // Display the content.
        Console.WriteLine (responseFromServer);
        // Clean up the streams.
        reader.Close ();
        dataStream.Close ();
        response.Close ();
    }
}
```

Comment: PS: I'd try and register steps for the aforementioned plugin as Asynchronous to avoid slowing dows operations too much

Comment: Doesn't this send a request to the server, not to the client?

Comment: OP needs to POST to a node.js application... Anyway, to me sending a request to a *client* doesn't really make sense but I might be missing something ?

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  We do use an HTML webpage and signalr to send messages to the client in Crm

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure no such solution is available out of the box, so your are going to be looking at custom development.

Comment: I found this post, but I was unable to assembly and register the plugin. http://h30507.www3.hp.com/t5/Applications-Services-Blog/Creating-a-near-real-time-streaming-interface-for-Dynamics-CRM/ba-p/178160#.VfKLoRGqpBc